# A problem in proving trigonometrical identities

Tags: trigonometry

I want to **graphically** prove $\sin(90^\circ-A)=\cos A$ and the follow up part.

I proceeded by drawing a circle of any radius $r$ on a right handed co-ordinate system and then considered the case where $90^\circ<A<180^\circ$. In this case $A$ lies on $2$nd quadrant so where will $90^\circ-A$ lie and how will the diagram look like?

Comment: can you use the Addition formulas?

Comment: Nope.... I'm​ just in the beginning stage....don't wanna use those formulae....wanna do it graphically

Comment: see here https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071008043056AAHn3R5 for your inspiration

Comment: I already know the formula -.- I'm on my way to prove it by considering different cases of angle A. So I'm stuck here of where will 90-A lie if A is in 2nd quadrant

Comment: $90^\circ - A$ is in the fourth quadrant.

Comment: @peterwhy How can you tell?

Comment: $$90^\circ < A < 180^\circ\\
-180^\circ < -A < -90^\circ\\
-90^\circ < 90^\circ - A < 0^\circ$$